# Issue with domain redirection

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain

I have a flash games website which is hosted at godaddy server. But because of heavy traffic on my site the godaddy server gets down. So I changed the hosting to Midphase server. The strange thing is i have created new name servers and new database in my mid phase server but still the web site is coming from the godaddy server.

When i do any modifications from the godaddy ftp i am getting the modifications but when i do any modifications in the mid phase server. No changes are happening. One strange thing is the *who.is* is showing the new name servers and new server details but not getting the new servers contents.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Sounds like DNS hasn't replicated fully yet.  How long has it been since you made this change?

Comment: Hey Steve thanks for immediate response...almost 6 hours have been completed since changes made...

Comment: DNS replication can sometimes take up to 72 hours.

Comment: What does intodns.com say about your domain?

Comment: They said minor issue with the DNS zone for the name servers. so said perform flush DNS. and delete browser coookies..i did it but still no change...

Comment: Check your DNS replication status using 'whereisitup.com' - love that site.

Comment: Hi thinice, i have checked..it shows 500 status message..